# Add color overlay to image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a demo for a web page I am working on here: https://jsfiddle.net/adh99rp4/.

Is there a way to have the green overlay appear over just the image and not the rest of the area?

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.content-block-inner {
    background: rgba(2, 79, 29, 0.8);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -khtml-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.content-block-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 300px;
}

article:hover .content-block-inner {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

<article class="post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-interiors" >

  <div class="entry-image">
   <div class="image-placeholder lazy-load">
    <div class="image-placeholder-container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/480x480" class="lazy-load">
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>

  <div class="content-block-inner">

   <div class="content-block-text">

    <header class="entry-header">

       <h3 class="entry-title">
      <a href="#" rel="bookmark">Header Text</a>
     </h3>
     <div class="entry-subtitle date">
      <a href="#" rel="bookmark">
       <time class="entry-date published" datetime="">Tuesday 29th December 2015</time>
      </a>    
     </div>
     
    </header>

    <div class="hr"></div>

   </div>

  </div>

 </article>

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: A cursory search of SO would show that this has been asked *thousands* of times before

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/adh99rp4/2/

Comment: Many thanks, Arun! :-) Can you please add as an Answer and I will accept? In the meantime, I'm going to look at how you put it together - greatly appreciated.